# Calling from a public class and from its public method, into 2d double array, my zeros before the fractional point change to number 9

Tags: c#

I've been writing a program, to use it as a tool for quick calculations in an online game, and it also helps me a bit to revise C# for my final exam in IT.

Here's my code:

```
public class ConvertingToArrays
{
   public static double[,] CountryVAT(double[,] vat)
    {
        //I have a table in a .txt file with 20 rows and 6 columns 
        //and I only need one of the cols.

        vat = new double[20, 1];
        string[,] convertTableToString = new string[20, 6];

        //Here I'm just calling from ReadFromFile public class and its 
        //public static string[,] Input method and until this point
        //everything works fine

        convertTableToString = ReadFromFile.Input(convertTableToString);            
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
            {
                vat[i, j] = double.Parse(convertTableToString[i, 1]);

            }
        }

        return vat;
    }
}
```

With the string to double converting I had no problem, I tested it and it should not be the cause.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[,] vat = new double[20, 1];
        vat = ConvertingToArrays.CountryVAT(vat);
        Console.WriteLine("Testing ConvertVAT Method Call");
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(vat[i, j] + '\t');
            }
            Console.WriteLine('\n');

        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I'm reading from a .txt file a few numbers like: 0,03; 0,05; 0,4; 0

And for some reason the output for these numbers are: 9,03; 9,05; 9,4; 9

I've tried to look it up on Google but I found nothing. It might be just one subtle and easy thing that I overlooked accidentally (please keep in mind that I have started learning to code by myself just 6 months before and I've practised it only 10-12 hours a week).

Can anyone help with a solution?

Comment: Please read [mcve] guidance on posting code and make sure post includes all necessary info, including data (preferably inline in the code as constants)

Comment: Your game has VAT in it? What's the game - "Tax Simulator"?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
Console.Write(vat[i, j] + '\t');
```

What is going on here? You add a `double` with a `char` value. You think you do some string operation, but that is not what your code is actually doing. Note that no strings are involved in the operation above. Both the double variable and the char literal are numeric data types, thus your code is executing an addition of the two numeric values.

What is the numeric value of the tabulator char `'\t'`? It is 9. So basically your code is doing `Console.Write(vat[i, j] + 9);`

There are different ways to you can change the code. One is to make two Console.Write calls like this:

```
Console.Write(vat[i, j]);
Console.Write('\t');
```

Alternatively, you could also force a string concatenation by converting the double value or the tab char to a string before "adding" them:

```
Console.Write(vat[i, j] + "\t");
```

or, less elegantly:

```
Console.Write(vat[i, j].ToString() + '\t');
```

As a third option you could also use format strings:

```
Console.Write("{0}{1}", vat[i, j], '\t');
```

or, simplified:

```
Console.Write("{0}\t", vat[i, j]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess I have to get back and learn the theory and rules of using character constants.

Comment: Not much to learn. Just remember that the char datatype in C# is numeric. The only meaningful difference between char and other numeric data types such as int or float is that char is for 16-bit character codes (which are essentially numbers ;) )